# Is there a tree like multiple choice survey app?

Tags: web-apps, survey, polls

There are already many web applications out there, that offer you to create your own survey/poll. Most though are rather too simplistic in my case and thus I am looking for one supporting certain properties:

I imagine the survey to be decision tree like: At every node of tree you make a choice and are lead to the next question until you reach a leaf node. The leaf node is then a result and shows many people have selected this as their preference.
Is there such an application?

Bonus, if the application allows for ranked voting or weighted voting etc.